# Focus on application debug point rather than on library in intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

While I am running jetty server on idea intellij in debug mode, focus moves to library classes. I want to concentrate on my application debug point rather than library i.e. I want to exclude all libraries from debugging. How can I achieve that??